# How to get archive in cpio format with 7zip command line

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -tcpio initrd initrdcpio\bst
mods\bstnet.ko

I have tried this command, but got an error

Comment: So what was the error?

Answer (score 2):

In the web site of [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/):

> Supported formats:
>   - Packing / unpacking: 7z, XZ, BZIP2, GZIP, TAR, ZIP and WIM
>   - Unpacking only: AR, ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO,...

So 7-Zip can not add files into a CPIO archive.